# Beamer subfigure numbering

Tags: beamer, subfloats

Is it possible to continue the sub-figure numbering across two frames in beamer?

I have four figures which are placed using subfigure, and need to place two on one frame and two on another. The ones on the first should be numbered (a) and (b), and the ones on the second should be (c) and (d).

Basic code

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{1.png}
 \caption{Fig1}
 \label{fig:1}
 \end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{2.png}
 \caption{Fig2}
 \label{fig:2}
 \end{subfigure}
\caption{Caption.}
\label{fig:caption}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{3.png}
 \caption{Fig3}
 \label{fig:3}
 \end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{4.png}
 \caption{Fig4}
 \label{fig:4}
 \end{subfigure}
\caption{Caption.}
\label{fig:caption}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but probably not automatically. You need to adjust `subfigure` counter on next slide (frame) on desired value. If you will provide minimal working example, it will be more easy to help you.

Comment: I have added an example in the question, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{subfig}

    \begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
\subfloat[Fig1 \label{fig:1}]{
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
\subfloat[Fig2 \label{fig:2}]{
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
\caption{Caption.}
\label{fig:caption}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}
    \addtocounter{subfigure}{2}
\centering
    \centering
\subfloat[Fig3 \label{fig:3}]{
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
\subfloat[Fig4 \label{fig:4}]{
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
\caption{Caption.}
\label{fig:caption}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

I consider that `subfigure` is obsolete and it is replace width `subfig` or `subcaption`. In my MWE I select `subfig`.

[image]